# Question About Sampling from Conditional Distribution Created from Approximated Distribution

Tags: probability-or-statistics, random

First, set the data and prepare the conditional distribution.
`pxy` is **joint** distribution of Random Variable `x` and`y`.
`py` is **marginal** distribution for variable `y` of `pxy`
`pcxy` is **conditional** distribution(distribution when **x==0**)

```
data = RandomFunction[WienerProcess[0, 1], {0, 1, 0.01}, 1000];
data // Normal // #[[All, 2]] & /@ # & // Set[sample, #] &;

Table[Transpose@{sample[[All, i]], sample[[All, i + 1]]}, {i, 1, 
      99}] // Flatten[#, 1] & // KernelMixtureDistribution // 
  Set[pxy, #] &;
px = MarginalDistribution[pxy, 1];
pcxy = PDF[pxy, {0, y}]/PDF[px, 0];
```

**What I want to do is sampling** from `pcxy` quickly,or fast as long as possible.

`Plot[pcxy, {y, -1, 1}]`
[image]

What I've tried is the following(this didn't end at all):

```
ProbabilityDistribution[pcxy, {y, -Infinity, Infinity}]
RandomVariate[%, 3] // AbsoluteTiming
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason it's slow is that the PDF of KernelMixture distributions is given symbolically. This can lead to very large expressions if you're using a lot of points, which would then need to be integrated for RandomVariate to work.

Using an interpolated PDF is a decent alternative

```
data = RandomFunction[WienerProcess[0, 1], {0, 1, 0.01}, 1000];

sample = data["ValueList"];

pxy = KernelMixtureDistribution[
    Flatten[Transpose /@ Partition[Transpose[sample[[;;, ;; 100]]], 2, 1], 1]
];

px = MarginalDistribution[pxy, 1];

pcxypdf = Interpolation[
    Table[{y, PDF[pxy, {0.0, y}] / PDF[px, 0.0]}, {y, -1, 1, 0.01}]
];

pcxy = ProbabilityDistribution[pcxypdf[y], {y, -1, 1}];

RandomVariate[pcxy, 1000] // AbsoluteTiming // First
(* 0.062171 *)

Show[
    Plot[PDF[pxy, {0, y}] / PDF[px, 0], {y, -1, 1}, PlotStyle -> Red],
    SmoothHistogram[RandomVariate[pcxy, 1000], Automatic, "PDF"],
    ImageSize -> Large
]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

One expects the conditional distribution to look very much like a normal distribution and indeed your plot of the estimated density shows that.  Therefore, you could sample from a normal distribution with the same mean and standard deviation as the estimated conditional distribution.

```
data = RandomFunction[WienerProcess[0, 1], {0, 1, 0.01}, 1000];
data // Normal // #[[All, 2]] & /@ # & // Set[sample, #] &;

Table[Transpose@{sample[[All, i]], sample[[All, i + 1]]}, {i, 1, 
      99}] //
    Flatten[#, 1] & // KernelMixtureDistribution // Set[pxy, #] &;
px = MarginalDistribution[pxy, 1];
pcxy = PDF[pxy, {0, y}]/PDF[px, 0];

ymean = NIntegrate[y pcxy, {y, -1, 1}]
ysd = NIntegrate[(y - ymean)^2 pcxy, {y, -1, 1}]^0.5
Plot[{pcxy, PDF[NormalDistribution[ymean, ysd], y]}, {y, -1, 1},
 PlotStyle -> {{Thickness[0.02], LightGray}, {Thin, Red}}]
```

[image: Conditional distribution and normal approximation]

Future samples could then be found with

```
yFuture = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[ymean, ysd], 100];
```